# Crear una tabla con cabecera fija con ts

Tags: html, css, typescript, html-tabla

llevo un tiempo intentando crear una tabla que tenga una cabecera fija, es decir que cuando haga un scroll la cabecera se mantenga en donde esta. He probado casi todos los ejemplos de internet que he visto y aunque alguno parecía que funcionaba pero sin suerte.

Código:

```css
.venta {
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    //table-layout: fixed;
}
.venta table thead {
    background-color: green;
    //position: fixed;
}
.venta table thead tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.venta table tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:white;
}
.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.selectRow {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class = "venta">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%"></th>
                <th width="10%">CÓDIGO</th>
                <th width="30%">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                <th width="15%">CANT.</th>
                <th width="15%">PRECIO</th>
                <th width="15%">DTO.(%)</th>
                <th width="10%">IMPORTE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let i = 0; i < 20; ++i" [ngClass]="selectedRow == i ? 'selectRow' : 'nonSelectRow'">
                <td width="5%">Valor 1</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 2</td>
                <td width="30%"> Valor 3</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 4</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 5</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 6</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 7</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Obviamente el hecho de que itere sobre i es para mostrar las lineas lo que hago en mi código es iterar sobre un array de objetos y los campos que se muestran son los valores de los campos de los objetos, creo que no debería influir y solo lo hará más díficl de leer así que los que quitado.
selectedRow es una variable que mediante una función de type script le assigna un numero de linea cuando se clica sobre ella.
Me interesaría mucho que en la respuesta se me permita también poner tamaños variables a casi todo.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he encontrado se arreglaba poniendo el codigo del th así:

```
.venta table thead {
background-color: green;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

Seguramente la primera respuesta era correcta pero al estar corriendolo desde localhost no me iba.

Comment: Claro que los has encontrado si es exactamente lo que te he dado de respuesta

Comment: Primero de todo recalcar que en ningún momento he querido que pareciera que la respuesta mía era solo mía y por ello en ella te doy crédito a ti. Segundo y más importante sin la línea de "position: -webkit-sticky;" no funciona y encontraba mal decir que tu respuesta era la correcta cuando no lo era. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad [sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) en tu thead, y ojo hay colocar el top también

```
.venta table thead {
    background-color: green;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```css
.venta {
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    //table-layout: fixed;
}
.venta table thead {
    background-color: green;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.venta table thead th {

}

.venta table thead tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.venta table tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:white;
}
.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.selectRow {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class = "venta" border="1">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%"></th>
                <th width="10%">CÓDIGO</th>
                <th width="30%">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                <th width="15%">CANT.</th>
                <th width="15%">PRECIO</th>
                <th width="15%">DTO.(%)</th>
                <th width="10%">IMPORTE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <script>
            for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
              document.write(`<tr>
                <td width="5%">Valor 1 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 2 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="30%"> Valor 3 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 4 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 5 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 6 - ${i}</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 7 - ${i}</td>
              </tr>`);
            }
           </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El sticky no funcionará en algunos navegadores si se aplica directamente al thead. Pero lo que sí puedes hacer es aplicárselo a un div que esté por encima:

```css
.cabecera-tabla { position: sitcky; top: 0; }
.venta {
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    //table-layout: fixed;
}
.venta table thead {
    background-color: green;
    //position: fixed;
}
.venta table thead tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.venta table tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.venta table tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:white;
}
.nonSelectRow td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.selectRow {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class = "venta">
  <div class="cabecera-tabla">
    <table>
      <thead cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="5%"></th>
                <th width="10%">CÓDIGO</th>
                <th width="30%">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                <th width="15%">CANT.</th>
                <th width="15%">PRECIO</th>
                <th width="15%">DTO.(%)</th>
                <th width="10%">IMPORTE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let i = 0; i < 20; ++i" [ngClass]="selectedRow == i ? 'selectRow' : 'nonSelectRow'">
                <td width="5%">Valor 1</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 2</td>
                <td width="30%"> Valor 3</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 4</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 5</td>
                <td width="15%">Valor 6</td>
                <td width="10%">Valor 7</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No ha funcionado. Si sirve de algo estoy usando Firefox.